# Recommended tutorial for character creation, rigging and weight painting?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

What is your recommended tutorial for character creation, rigging and weight painting?

I have watched so many YouTube tutorials on this and most don't go into detail or explain at all WHY they are doing something. Which to a new blender user, would not make sense. As I'm working on my own model not on whatever they are doing in the tutorial some things just go wrong.

I have been working on making a model from scratch to make for VRChat expecting it to only take 3 days has now taken now over a week working on it 12 hours a day. Even some all-nighters. No, this is not an exaggeration.

I've remade/re-edited my model about 25 times now and the joints still are very jagged when they move in VRChat.

I do best learning with Pictures and words rather than just textbook-words. Video is ok too.

Yes, posting on these forums is helpful at times but I'd much rather prefer for my problem to be solved as soon as possible. Rather than waiting for a response and in the mean-time ruining my character more in order to try and work out a solution myself. Most of my problems come from not pressing 1 key.

I don't want someone to do it for me, I want to learn how to do it myself.

I honestly just want to know how to make my character perfectly. I will buy any plugins or pay a tutor or video service to just explain it to me properly.

Is there some kind of website where I can pay to ask a blender-pro any question about blender in exchange for money? I know that my problems take a long time to explain especially because I want a screen shot or step-by-step walkthrough of how to do something or how to fix something with the reason WHY and just explaining what each tool does. It doesn't have to go into a lot of detail just enough for me to understand.

Can anyone give me some advice or links to where I can accomplish this?

Comment: You'll find a lot of tutorials about rigging in Youtube, watch a lot of them: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+base+of+riging  ...   https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+character+rigging    at the beginning it will be hard, try to rig your own shapes and characters, then come back to these tutorials, then you'll understand how it works

Comment: Asking for tutorials, links for tutorials or recommended resourcess is considered off-topic as it is too broad and mostly opinion based. Please read: [What is the proper action for a question that requests links to tutorials](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2380/what-is-the-proper-action-for-a-question-that-requests-links-to-tutorials)

Comment: Sorry. As I am new to blender I can not possibly comprehend how complex or broad something like rigging or sculpting really is. I just wouldn't know. I just assumed it was something simple that anyone besides me would be able to help with. Also, as I'm new to blender I do not know how to navigate these forums and can not find these threads that mayaswell be hidden to me. I will try to avoid asking questions anymore as I don't want to get banned for something I can't remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rigging concepts go beyond software specific knowledge. The resource I've found most helpful in solidifying the understanding of such concepts can be found in [The Animator Friendly Rigging Series](http://jasonschleifer.com/afr/) by Jason Schleifer. 
Once you have a good grasp of parent child relationships and constraints and how objects behave under different spaces and deformations. You can apply that knowledge to rig anything to have the specific control behavior for animation.

[Rigging Dojo](https://www.riggingdojo.com/) is also a great resource to tap into.